# SHELL regular expression ends with backslash

Tags: shell

I want to check if the pattern ends with "/" or "\" and before it can be any string.

I tried this

```
*\/
```

`*` for any string,    `\` for removing meaning of "/"   and `/` for "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[/\\]$
```

That is, a forward slash or a backward slash, followed by end-of-string.

There are many "flavours" of regular expressions: what tool are you using?

Comment: what do you mean by a tool?.. It looks like it doesn't work but that's probably because I am trying to use it in "if condition" :(

Comment: bash? `[[ $string =~ [/\\]$ ]]`

Comment: The problem is it needs to work in any shell. But with bash this works. Thanks again.

Comment: If it needs to work in any shell, then you can't rely on the shell to test it: you have to call an external program: `expr "$string" : '.*[/\\]$'` may be the most portable test.